# How to add an IF block with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

In the file `script.js` I have a function, which opens pages as a construction from `http://www.example.com/#url=` and `var theUrl`, which gets the value of user's input, like `http://www.usersurl.com`. The code looks like:

```
    if (theUrl != "") {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url:
                "http://www.example.com/#url=" +
                theUrl,
            selected: false
        });
    }
```

As result new tab with an address `http://www.example.com/#url=http://www.usersurl.com` is opening.

I have a `popup.html` too, where user inputs url into form's textfield.

Until now everything works like it should.

Now i want to add to `popup.html` checkboxes, checking of which will add additional `chrome.tabs.create` blocks with different URLs. Something like this:

**popup.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1">checkbox1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" value="checkbox2">
<label for="checkbox2">checkbox2</label><br>
```

**script.js**

```
    if (theUrl != "") && checkbox1="checked" {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url:
                "http://www.example.com/#url=" +
                theUrl,
            selected: false
        });
    }

    if (theUrl != "") && checkbox2="checked" {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url:
                "http://www.anothersite.com/#url=" +
                theUrl,
            selected: false
        });
    }
```

What is the way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify if a checkbox is checked or not by by using the `checked` property which will return a boolean based on whether the checkbox is checked or not like this:

```
const checkbx1 = document.querySelector('#checkbox1');
const checkbx2 = document.querySelector('#checkbox2');

if ((theUrl != "") && checkbox1.checked) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url:
    "http://www.example.com/#url=" +
    theUrl,
    selected: false
  });
}

if ((theUrl != "") && checkbox2.checked) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url:
    "http://www.anothersite.com/#url=" +
    theUrl,
    selected: false
  });
}
```

---

Also, since you have a common condition `theUrl != ""` in your two if statements, you can use a common if statement for that condition like this:

```
const checkbx1 = document.querySelector('#checkbox1');
const checkbx2 = document.querySelector('#checkbox2');

if (theUrl != "") {
  if (checkbox1.checked) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url:
      "http://www.example.com/#url=" + theUrl,
      selected: false
    });
  }
  if (checkbox2.checked) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url:
      "http://www.example.com/#url=" + theUrl,
      selected: false
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for the `checked` property of the checkbox inputs to determine which ones are selected. However, using an `if` statement for each case, although correct, can become challenging if the number of checkboxes increases. I would recommend using a loop through all selected checkboxes using a CSS selector, for example:

**popup.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox" value="http://example.com/#url=">
<label for="checkbox1">Open with example</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox" value="http://anothersite.com/#url=">
<label for="checkbox2">Open with anothersite</label><br>
```

**script.js**

```
if (theUrl) {
    document.querySelectorAll('[name=checkbox]:checked').forEach(chosen => {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: chosen.value + theUrl,
            selected: false
        });
    });
}
```

This way you can add as many checkboxes as you want without having to change the code, improving efficiency and maintainability.